# console.log is different from json.push

Tags: json, google-cloud-firestore, console.log

I am using node.js to export a collection that I have in firestore.

Until now the connection and the selection of the documents of the collection work perfectly.

I am trying to save the structure in a json file but the result is not what I expected.

This is the output in the physical file:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQZ5G.png)

On the right of the photo, it will be seen as presented by the console.log and on the right it is displayed as recorded by json.push

I can't get the physical file to have the structure shown in the console.log.

I appreciate all your help.

as you will see the structure here is failing:   "USBCALI|AFILIADO|uqcMSoxdwCTQoLzS2J6brNTZ3Dy2",
  ":",
  {.....

should be: USBCALI|AFILIADO|uqcMSoxdwCTQoLzS2J6brNTZ3Dy2 : {.....

this is the code

```html
const jsonfile = require('jsonfile')

function start (db, file, collection) {
  const ref = db.collection(collection)
  const json = []

  

  console.log(`Getting ${collection}...`)

  ref
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {  
        console.log(doc.id, ':', doc.data())
 json.push(doc.id, ':', doc.data())
      })

      console.log(`Writing ${file}...`)

      jsonfile.writeFile(file, json, {spaces: 2}, err => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err)
        } else {
          console.log(`Collection ${collection} successfully written to ${file}.`)
        }
      })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Error getting documents', err)
    })
}

module.exports = start
```

Comment: This is just a guess but when you're persisting your data to wherever are you wrapping the keys in quotes? I'm wondering whether if you have atmepted to persist them without quotes as is implied by the left hand screenshot which has confused whatever is parsing them. The reason I ask this is because the keys do not appear to be quoted on the left hand side of the screen shot and I wonder if the pipe symbol is even a valid javascript symbol character for variables

Comment: I think you should do a map function to extract the data properly rather than this crazy string operation back to object you are doing, give me a moment I will help you

Comment: the pipe "|" in this case it is part of the document key in firestore. and in this case it does not cause problems.

my biggest problem is wanting to save a json that includes the document key.

in the console.log it appears well structured, but I don't understand why it changes when I store it in the json.push, even with the same line.

I hope I have been a little clearer.

thanks for your help.

Comment: thank you very much max carroll i am really just starting to handle the issue. you're very kind.

Comment: I think I got it! Check my answer and see if it worked, the problem is how your pushing to the array, that will not work, you are pushing 2 strings and an object to the array each time not the object how you think. With a map function we can properly create objects derived from each doc. I didn't test my code I just did it in my head let me know if it doesn't work and I'll adjust my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain whats going on here

`console.log(doc.id, ':', doc.data())`

Is logging out the information how you would *think* you would like it to be

`json.push(doc.id, ':', doc.data())` is pushing 3 elements into the array every time its called.

What you really want to do is manipulate the data properly into an object using a map function. I'm making some assumptions based on all the info I have here, but I'm guessing you want to do something like

```
var docs snapshot.map( doc =>  ({[doc.id] : doc.data()})
json.push(docs)
```

instead of

```
 snapshot.forEach((doc) => {  
        console.log(doc.id, ':', doc.data())
    json.push(doc.id, ':', doc.data())
      })
```

You could also do (this is a bit more verbose than the map method but will essentially do the same thing. The map function is like select in sql or Linq, its handy to transform data from one form into another

```
 snapshot.forEach((doc) => {  
    var currentItem = {[doc.id] : doc.data()}
    json.push(currentItem)
      })
```

Since you have used some es6 notation, I'm assuming that Computed Property Names are supports, if not let me know and Ill come up with another soloution

Comment: Awesome!, your homework is to master the map function and then try playing with filter, find and reduce . These will really help you